# Having two storyboards use the same ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode-storyboard

Im relatively new to iphone development, as Im doing my first steps.
I started with a 1 MVC iPhone application, and since its more convenient to me to use my ipad for dev., I decided to add another view for iPad.
I added the new storyboard and defined it as the one for ipad target, but I cant make outlet/action connections to my original viewcontroller.
Its the exact same view, so why cant I?

Comment: Did you set its class?

Comment: Yes, It is defined as UIViewController

Comment: Can you show what exactly you are doing?

Comment: Well, I dont know How I can show it here. I simply added a new storyboard, it is well defined (it loads fine when I use it for my ipad), but I cant make any outlet connections or actions to my ViewController.m which I already have written for my iphone storyboard. How can I define it to be the controller for the ipad storyboard as well?